# How to read last message in Chronicle long rolled over

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I want to read the last message written to a SingleChronicleQueue instance.

While "chronicle.createTailer().direction(TailerDirection.BACKWARD).toEnd()" works while we are on the same cycle as the last written message, as soon as we are in one of the future cycles (compared to the last written message), tailer.readDocument(...) always returns "false".

I have implemented a test to reproduce the issue based on the  [SingleChronicleQueueTest.testForwardFollowedBackBackwardTailer](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/impl/single/SingleChronicleQueueTest.java#L1573) test:

```
@Test
public void testForwardFollowedBackBackwardTailer() {
    File tmpDir = getTmpDir();

    // when "forwardToFuture" flag is set, go one day to the future
    AtomicBoolean forwardToFuture = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    TimeProvider timeProvider = () -> forwardToFuture.get()
            ? System.currentTimeMillis() + Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis() 
            : System.currentTimeMillis();

    try (RollingChronicleQueue chronicle = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(tmpDir)
            .rollCycle(TEST2_DAILY)
            .wireType(this.wireType)
            .timeProvider(timeProvider)
            .build()) {

        ExcerptAppender appender = chronicle.acquireAppender();

        int entries = chronicle.rollCycle().defaultIndexSpacing() + 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            appender.writeDocument(w -> w.writeEventName("hello").text("world" + finalI));
        }

        // go to the future (and to the next roll cycle)
        forwardToFuture.set(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            readForward(chronicle, entries);
            readBackward(chronicle, entries);
        }
    }
}
```

After these changes to the "testForwardFollowedBackBackwardTailer" method,
the test fails at [assertTrue(documentContext.isPresent()) line in the "readBackward" method](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/impl/single/SingleChronicleQueueTest.java#L1623).

Is there any way to reliably read the last message from SingleChronicleQueue instance, no matter how far in the past the last message is? (without reading through the whole chronicle instance from the start)

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using as this should work. If you have the latest version, it is a bug.

Can you submit a pull request with this unit test?

Comment: I am using "4.5.15", the latest i found in maven.

Comment: Sure, I'll submit a pull request.